# Using jQuery to assign one element a class when another is hovered over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create effects on the sides of the page that will appear when a div in the center of the page is hovered over. I'm using jQuery to do this.

I've tried my most useful diagnosing technique (using alerts for parts of my JS) and I cannot seem to figure out why my code isn't running.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.2'></script>
<script>
  $( "#shadow" ).hover(
    function() {
      $( "#wingRight" ).addClass( "shown" );
    }, function() {
      $( "#wingRight" ).removeClass( "shown" );
    }
  );
  $( "#light" ).hover(
    function() {
      $( "#wingLeft" ).addClass( "shown" );
    }, function() {
      $( "#wingLeft" ).removeClass( "shown" );
    }
  );
</script>
```

[Heres my code pen for the site so far](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzVVqO)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You dont have any content in the id="wingLeft" and id="wingRight". Try to add some content and see

Comment: Plus its good to bind the events in the $(function(){ //your event binding }); so that it gets run on document load

Comment: @GvM that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: the div wingLeft and wingRight should have a height or content so you could check if your code is working.

Comment: try to check @Sean

Comment: The problem is as @RaniMorelesRubillos says, they don't have heights.  If you add some temporary content to the wingLeft and wingRight divs then you'll see your code works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of an element is based on its contents. When you assign height as a percentage, as you did with #wingLeft and #wingRight, you are taking 100% of 0, which is 0.

If your class assigns a hard value to the height, such as 100px, your jQuery works just fine. Here is your updated pen.

http://codepen.io/WallyNally/pen/QKeeRj

Notice that giving them height also centers your Mandala.

PS - CodePen includes the `<head>` for you, and the `<script>` can go in the JS field. In the settings tab you can load in jQuery without linking it in the text.

Comment: Thanks for providing a CodePen with yours. I set the height to 100% which I presumed would make it the full height of the body, which... Come to think of, not sure if I defined its height. They may have been an issue.

Comment: @SeanWoodfin, no prob. 
You may also be interested in the units `vw` and `vh`. They are the best of both words between percentage and fixed number. `100vw` is equal to 100% the viewport's width, and `100vh` is equal to 100% the viewport's height - the difference being that vw/vh are calculated as numbers instead of percentages. 
And yes, you always want to define the body's dimensions. My CSS almost always starts with `body {width: 100vw; height: 100vh;}`

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `#wingLeft` and `#wingRight` have `0 height` (at least that's what happens in your codepen).

Answer (score 0):

try to add a minheight on your wingLeft div and wingRight div so you could see the div that is hovered.

```
#wingLeft{
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
}
#wingRight{
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The element div #wingLeft and #wingRight should contain something or give them min-height.u will not see the div if no height was given or no child contains.